# How can I find what Loss Given Default to use

Tags: risk, risk-management, credit-risk, value-at-risk

I want to come up with the appropriate loss given default for a commodity derivative in my CVA calculation. would anyone know where I can find this information?

Comment: LGD depends on the counterparty recovery rate, the type of collateral, and the correlation between the underlying and the counterparty default. Information on the underlying only (here a commodity) is not sufficient to estimate LGD.